# How to remove redundant data in MySql subquery

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and having Mysql query like

```
select x.column1 as 'id', y.column1 as 'name' from (select id from table1 limit 1) as x, (select name from table2 limit 5) as y;
```

In the above case subquery 1 returns 1 row and subquery 2 returns 5 rows and the output be like

```
id     name
101    AAA
101    BBB
101    CCC
101    DDD
101    EEE
```

But my expectation is like

```
id     name
101    AAA
null   BBB
null   CCC
null   DDD
null   EEE
```

How can I get this output in MySql? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the data in the the two tables that should produce this result

Comment: Why `AAA` is joined whereas all another values are ignored? Formulate the criteria.

Comment: I would advise you to make 2 separate queries for this or use the `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT "your_column_name")` function for getting unique comma separated values

Comment: Not AAA is joined. i just tried to combine the results of two queries. Assume query 1 return 1 row and query 2 returns many rows